# How to handle route parameters in angular?

Tags: angular, refresh, page-refresh, angular7-router

My app is redirecting to "localhost:4200/teams/team1" on a button click where I initialize paramValue(name) and is loading proper component also, But when I refresh browser, it is not able to fetch route param value(name) and it redirects to PageNotFoundComponent. Please help me find the solution.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'',component:LandingPageComponent},
  {path:'teams/:name', canActivate:[AuthGuard], component: TeamComponent},

  {path:'error-handler',component:ErrorHandlerComponent},
  {path: '**', component:PageNotFoundComponent ,pathMatch:'full'}

];
```

Comment: where do you initialize (name) route param value?

Comment: `<span class="team-name-sidebar"  [routerLink]="['teams',team.teamName]" >{{team.teamName}}</span>`

It is getting initialized on the sidebar component of my app where the list of teams is displayed.

Comment: have you fetched value in team component ts.

Comment: yes 

`this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.teamName = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('name');
}`

Comment: team.teamName has value assigned to it?

Comment: yes. It is getting fetched from database.

Comment: Then on page refresh it wont vanish.

Comment: Setup demo or share code snippet